# Apex trigger - populate field value in object A from Object B

Tags: apex, trigger

I am a beginner on this apex endeavours. I can interpret code but I struggle on creating it.

So I just need to understand how to create a trigger to update a field from one custom object (A) to another (B).

If you can provide comments on all the steps for me to understand the why, that would be great

I came up with this, but it is not working (but i was able to save it):

```
trigger PopulateOrderValue on ObjectA__c (before insert) { 
    ObjectB__c bb = [Select FieldsB__c from ObjectB__c]; 
    for(objectA__c aa : trigger.new) { 
        aa.fieldA__c = bb.FieldB__c; 
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you are trying to achieve. How are ObjectA__c and ObjectB__c related?

Comment: Yes the is a lookup relationship from Obj B to object A. 
i was able to modify the trigger logic and save it on salesforce but it is not updating the field still


`code`

trigger PopulateOrderValue on ObjectA__c (before insert)  {

ObjectB__c bb = [Select FieldsB__c from ObjectB__c];

for(objectA__c aa : trigger.new)
{
aa.fieldA__c = bb.FieldB__c;

}    


}

Comment: Is it possible that multiple ObjectBs have a lookup to the same ObjectA?

Comment: Perhaps for your stage of knowledge a mix of Apex and Workflow field updates might be an approach. Simply get a list of all B's that are related to A (I assume B is a "child" of A) and touch them using Upsert. This will trigger a workflow which can then make all the field allocations you need using a friendlier environment, that on a good day with a following wind you may be able to pass onto a non IT expert resource.

Comment: You don't need a trigger to do this, a Workflow will be able to do this.

Comment: Your trigger as it is written will only work when ObjectA is created.  In fact, technically before it's created.  It sounds like you want to do this on Update.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example assuming that there if there is only one child record that all get updated:

```
trigger PopulateOrderValue on ObjectA__c (before insert) { 

//A map of object B records
Map<ID,ObjectB__c> bbMap = New Map<ID,objectB__c>();

//populate the Map of Object B records usinf the relationship field as the key 
for(ObjectB__c b : [Select FieldsB__c, ObjectA_Relationship_Field__C From ObjectB__c Where ObjectA_Relationship_Field__C IN trigger.new]){

bbMap.put(b.ObjectA_Relationship_Field__C,b);


}

    for(objectA__c aa : trigger.new) { 

//Set to null if not found
aa.fieldA__c = bbMap.containsKey(aa.id) ? bbMap.get(aa.id).FieldB__c : null ; 
//Or you can do it this way to ignore
if(bbMap.containsKey(aa.id))
    aa.FieldA__c = bbMap.get(aa.id).FieldB__c;

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have two bank accounts (object type `Bank_Account__c`) and a Transfer object (object type `Transfer__c`), and for every new transfer object, you needed to update each bank accounts balance.

So our object types are:

```
Objects: 
Bank_Account__c
Transfer__c
```

A transfer ( `Transfer__c` ) will have the following fields:

```
Amount__c (Currency)
Transfer_From__c (Lookup relationship)
Transfer_To__c (Lookup Relationship)
```

And a bank account ( `Bank_Account__c` ) will have the following fields

```
Name
Balance__c (Currency)
```

NOTE: In this case a transfer probably has an auto number associated with it, but it is irrelevant for this example.

The code will look like this:

```
trigger transferBetweenAccounts on Transfer__c (after insert) {

if(Trigger.isAfter){

    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        for(Transfer__c transfer : Trigger.new){

        //   We need to first retrieve our bank accounts records from the data base.

        //   A relationship field (in the Transfer object, in this case) will store
        //   a record ID of the related object (in this case, two Bank accounts).

        //   We do a database query looking for a bank account of the IDs from
        //   the transfer fields, hence:
        //   WHERE Id = :transfer.Transfer_To__c LIMIT 1
        //   and
        //   WHERE Id = :transfer.Transfer_From__c LIMIT 1

        //   Since we are filtering by object ID, only one object in the Bank account 
        //   database will match our query, but I use LIMI 1 for safety anyway.

        Bank_Account__c toAccount = [SELECT Id, Name, Amount__c FROM Bank__Account__c WHERE Id = :transfer.Transfer_To__c LIMIT 1];
        Bank_Account__c fromAccount = [SELECT Id, Name, Amount__c FROM Bank_Account__c WHERE Id = :transfer.Transfer_From__c LIMIT 1];

        toAccount.Amount__c += transfer.Amount__c;
        fromAccount.Amount__c -= transfer.Amount__c;

        update toAccount;
        update fromAccount;

    }

}
```

}

And that's it!  Now, you will want to handle other cases such as the case where the Balance fields are null/initialized, and you will also want to add conditional statements for the case when a transfer is deleted or updated too, but it is very straightforward.